# Calculating probabilities given CDF

Tags: probability, random

Let $X$ be a random variable with CDF:
$$
F_{X}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0, & \textrm{$x<-1$}\\
\frac{1}{2}, & \textrm{$-1\leq x<3$}\\
1-e^{-x}, & \textrm{$ 3\leq x $}
\end{array} \right.
$$
How to compute

- $\mathbb{P}(|X-2|>1/2)$
- $\mathbb{P}(|X-2|>1)$
- $\mathbb{P}(\min(3,X)>4)$
- $\mathbb{P}(\min(3,X)<4)$
- $\mathbb{P}(\max(3,X)<4)$

***EDIT:*** For the first one I got
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X-2|>1/2) = \mathbb{P}(X-2>1/2)+\mathbb{P}(X-2<-1/2) =\mathbb{P}(X>5/2)+\mathbb{P}(X<3/2)=\\=1-1/2+1/2=1$$
Similarly second one I get $e^{-3}$.
Then third probability I tried using conditional probability like this
$$ \mathbb{P}(\min(3,X)>4)= \mathbb{P}(3>4|X\geq3)+\mathbb{P}(X>4|X\leq3)=0$$
Other min-max probabilities I tried the same way but I think it is wrong approach.

Comment: You would learn a lot more in the long run if you post your work and have the people here guide you to the right track rather than (politely) asking people to spoon-feed you step-by-step solutions to what appears to be homework.

Comment: Alright, I have added my work. By the way, it is not any homework, just an exercise from problem set which I want to do correctly and understand.

Comment: I obtain $\mathbb{P}(|X-2|>1/2)=1$ too, but $\mathbb{P}(|X-2|>1)=1/2+e^{-3}$. Might I suggest using the relation $\{|X-a|>c\}=\{|X-a|\leq c\}^c$ so that $\mathbb{P}(|X-a|>c)=1-\mathbb{P}(|X-a|\leq c)=1-(F(a+c)-F(a-c))$. It is often easier dealing with complements of events like $\{|X-a|>c\}$. The conditional formula you cite is incorrect. You are forgetting to multiply by probability of the conditioned events: $\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_i \mathbb{P}(A|B_i)\mathbb{P}(B_i).$ Though this comment is too late now.

Comment: But now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $a<b$, we have $\mathbb P(a<X\le b)=\mathbb P(X\le b)-\mathbb P(X\le a)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$.

If the inequality is not strict on the left side, we have $\mathbb P(a\le X\le b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a-)$, where $F_X(a-)=\lim_{x\to a-}F_X(x)$.

We also have $\mathbb P(X<b)=F_X(b_-)$.

Then we have
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\vert X-2\vert>\frac12)&=1-\mathbb P(\vert X-2\vert\le\frac12)=1-\mathbb P(-\frac12\le X-2\le\frac12)\\
&=1-\mathbb P(\frac32\le X\le\frac52)=1-(F_X(\frac52)-F_X(\frac32-))\\
&=1-(\frac12-\frac12)=1.
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb P(\vert X-2\vert>1)&=1-\mathbb P(\vert X-2\vert\le 1)=1-\mathbb P(-1\le X-2\le1)\\
&=1-\mathbb P(1\le X\le 3)=1-(F_X(3)-F_X(1-))=1-(1-\textrm e^{-3}-\frac12)\\
&=\textrm e^{-3}+\frac12\cdot
\end{align*}$$

$\mathbb P(\min(3,X)>4)=0$ since $4>3\ge\min(3,X)$.

$\mathbb P(\min(3,X)<4)=1$ since $\min(3,X)\le 3<4$.

$\mathbb P(\max(3,X)<4)=\mathbb P(X<4)=F_X(4-)=1-\textrm e^{-4}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!